# iOS - Change color name in all XIBs or Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, storyboard, xib

How can I replace a specific color defined in Xcode and used in multiple XIBs and storyboards with a different color throughout the project?

Example :
How can I replace the color "MainPurple" with "MainYellow" in all XIBs and storyboards in Xcode where it is currently used, while ensuring that the change is applied consistently across the entire project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the terminal, Navigate to the project and run this command:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.xib' -or -name '*.storyboard' \) \

  -exec sed -E -i '' 's/([cC]olor.*)name="MainPurple"/\1name="MainYellow"/' {} \;
```

This searches in all XIBs and Storyboards for the color "MainPurple" whether used as a view color, button color, label color and so on , and replaces it with "MainYellow"